# remove words starting with @ in a dataframe column (python)

Tags: python, twitter

I have a dataframe in python with one column being filled with tweets. I am trying to remove all twitter handles from my dataframe. Any ideas how to do so.

I'm using python 2

[image]

If there are instances "@beyonce I Love your new album"
I want to remove the @beyonce

Comment: Is the `@` sign always in the beginning or no? your picture depicts otherwise

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: `str.replace` can take a regular expression.

Comment: The image you included doesn't show any instances of what you describe, and there is no code for what you have tried so far. Please review [How to ask a Minimal, Complete, and Verified Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this by using the ASCII code for the @ sign (according to this, it's 64 https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp). More specifically, you could split your tweets into an array, loop through that array and if the character is equal to 64 (or whatever the ASCII code for @ is), you could replace it with ''. Hope that helps!